# Redriect to external provider from AuthenticateLocalAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver3

Is it possible redirect to external provider (in my case: AAD) from custom User service in `AuthenticateLocalAsync` method ?

External provider depends on local user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed user login strategy. Now, user should choose his account provider on login page. All works as expected

Answer (score 1):

`AuthenticateLocalAsync` will execute after username and password is provided by user.

What you need to do is to set External Identity Provider in `PreAuthenticateAsync`

```
Task PreAuthenticateAsync(PreAuthenticationContext context)
{
    context.SignInMessage.IdP = "<EXTERNAL IDENTITY PROVIDER NAME>";
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

**Edit**

In case you need to first authenticate with username and password and then use External Identity Provider, I guess you should use the same mechanism for partial login.

in `AuthenticateLocalAsync` You should use [this constructor](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/dev/source/Core/Models/AuthenticateResult.cs#L184) method for creating `AuthenticateResult`. You set a redirect url and from there call Challenge for External Identity Provider

Comment: I know this solution but i need first to resolve user  from DB and next redirect to AAD  ( some users need to be validated by AAD)

Comment: yeah, i tried that solution before. I will try tomorrow again maybe i miss something. Thanks

Comment: Which Url i should use for `redirectPath` parameter?

Comment: I suggest you add a webapi middleware and add a controller with an action which calls `Challenge`, and redirect to that

Comment: Thans for your help. It works, but we changed user login strategy ( read my answer ).